# How to classify country names given possible alternate spellings or abbreviations?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, text-mining

Let's say I have a list of users who have specified the country they reside in by typing in something. I want to find the total number of users who came from the US, the UK, and everywhere else. But, since users typed in their country manually my data looks like this:

```
USER   COUNTRY
1      USA
2      United States
3      US
4      UK
5      England
...
```

Are there any public datasets or good algorithms to solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 4):

[Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) is a nice free solution for this, but it is likely that you will still have to do a fair bit of manual work.

Comment: This works pretty well for alternate spellings and upper/lowercase problems. Thanks. However, none of the clustering methods work well for state abbreviations. It's not hard to match those up. I guess the toughest problem I'm having is with cities: NYC, NY city, New York City, NY, nw yrk, etc. . .

Comment: I had good luck with the key collision clustering method using the metaphone3 function first, but that will confuse things like "Newark" and "New York", so you have to be careful. Did you already try the reconciliation service? With only one column, it was able to do all the NYC other than "nw yrk". It was not automatic, but I think if you have other columns like zip code and state, it will work better.

Comment: Here's another idea. Could you also get the country from the IP address of the survey takers? Most web surveys come bundled with that data.

Comment: It's strange. In the intro video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B70J_H_zAWM&feature=player_embedded), the use an example of matching "Firm Fixed Price" to "FFP", so it seems like "New York" and "NYC" should be easy to do.

Comment: The reconciliation method worked really well. This is actually a great solution. Thanks, Dimitriy.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest calculating the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between the entered string and a master list of known countries and country abbreviations.

Comment: I am not sure this will work so well. For example, Levenshtein distance between "US" and "United States" is 11, while for "US" "UK" it is 1. I think other distance measures suffer from similar problems. The nice thing about Google Refine is that is uses semantically-aware reconciliation services (such as Freebase's) to compensate for the deficiencies of syntax-level clustering alone.

Comment: @Dimitriy V. Masterov I supposed edit distance really only works for variant spellings and misspellings of the country name.  You could also include abbreviations on your list of known countries.